# how to write struct char to a file

Tags: c

```
typedef struct {
    const char *name;
    const unsigned char *data;
    const unsigned int size;
} Assembly;

void test(const Assembly **assemblies);

void test(const Assembly ** assemblies)
{

    //i want to print assemblies to a txt file.
    //like this：
    //name->XXX 
    //data->DDD
    //size->YYY
}

int main()
{
    test(bundled);
    return 0;
}
```

I just started to learn C ,This task is too difficult. 
 i donot know how to do this.
please help me.thaks!

I tried to do like this:
[image]

the problem is :

for each the char binary array,‘144’ was changed to -122

‘255’ changed to -1.

like the pic above!

how to get data {77, 90, 144, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255}
 and write it into a txt file.

Comment: What did you already try? How that did not work?

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: I am sorry for a bad question before . i changed my question.

Comment: it'd be more clear if you provide text examples of input and outputs rather than images... in the output what did you get for 255 and 255 ?

Comment: the data in  example maybe incorrect，but it just a test for get the data in the struct .

Comment: @SouravGhosh  give me Minus 4 points，i admits the question before is not good。but i changed that。i can not ask question any more。it is so unfair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is 144.. You write as unsigned char (from 0 to 255 )but it seem you read as char ( from -128 to 127 ). 
144 as unsigned char is [1001000]b. 
-112 as char is [10010000]b.
Nothing is wrong with your code.